# Why can't AWS Lambda receive SNS payload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I found articles how to send alerts from Amazon Prometheus to Microsoft Teams with AWS SNS & Lambda. I configured everything according to articles. When I send test payload in Lambda, everything is ok, Lambda sends a message. But when I send the same test payload with SNS, I receive an error in Lambda (look below). What is the problem with test payload or Lambda or SNS? SNS Subscription configured to Lambda correctly.

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'alertname'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/teams-alerting-lambda.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    alertname = message['alertname']
```

I added 'print(event)' command. When sending payload in SNS i receive in Lambda logs:

```
{'Records': [{'EventSource': 'aws:sns', 'EventVersion': '1.0', 'EventSubscriptionArn': 'ARN', 
'Sns': {'Type': 'Notification', 'MessageId': '', 'TopicArn': 'ARN', 'Subject': None, 
'Message': '{\n  "Records": [\n    {\n      
"Sns": {\n        
"Message": "{\\"alertname\\": \\"CPU_ALERT_333\\", \\"status\\": \\"firing\\", \\"host_name\\": \\"host1\\", \\"cloud_account_id\\": \\"1234567890\\", \\"cloud_region\\": \\"eu-west-1\\", \\"summary\\": \\"High CPU Load\\", \\"severity\\": \\"warning\\"}"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}', 
'Timestamp': 'TIME', 'SignatureVersion': '1', 'Signature': '...', 'SigningCertUrl': 'URL', 'UnsubscribeUrl': 'URL', 'MessageAttributes': {}}}]}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "Sns": {
        "Message": "{\"alertname\": \"CPU_Alert\", \"status\": \"firing\", \"host_name\": \"host1\", \"cloud_account_id\": \"1234567890\", \"cloud_region\": \"eu-west-1\", \"summary\": \"High CPU Load\", \"severity\": \"warning\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Part of Python code that is responsible for handling payload:

```
13 def lambda_handler(event, context):
14    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
15    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
16    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))
17
18    alertname = message['alertname']
19    status = message['status']
```

Comment: The code that you provided is fine. Please double check that the code and event payload that you provided are actually the ones that you are using.

Comment: @Marcin I checked the code, it is the one that I use for test payload. I removed some fields here to make it more understandable & to do a quick look on it.

Comment: So what is the actually `event` from sns?

Comment: @Marcin I updated payload

Comment: Its confusing. In the question you wrote that you have to payloads: one test and one sns. The one that you are showing is what?

Comment: @Marcin I use the same payload for Lambda & for SNS, is it wrong?

Comment: Can you add to your code `print(event)` and report what `event` actually is for the SNS? If this is what you have in question, then your code is perfectly fine and the issue lays outside of your code.

Comment: @Marcin i added print(event). Here is not enough space to add full msg. I receive this: {'Records': [{'EventSource': 'aws:sns', 'EventVersion': '1.0', 'EventSubscriptionArn': '...', 'Sns': {'Type': 'Notification', 'MessageId': '...', 'TopicArn': '...', 'Subject': ..., 'Message': '{\n  "Records": [\n    {\n      "Sns": {\n        "Message": "{\\"alertname\\": \\"CPU_ALERT_333\\", \\"status\\": \\"firing\\", \\"host_name\\": \\"host1\\", \\"cloud_account_id\\": \\"1234567890\\", \\"cloud_region\\": \\"eu-west-1\\", \\"summary\\": \\"High CPU Load\\", \\"severity\\": \\"warning\\"}"

Comment: @Please update the question with the new event. as you can is it is totally different than the example you provided in the question.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you should do and how to use `ast` package?

Comment: @Marcin I added line with ast, but it didnt help, i need to investigate how exactly this command works, thx.

Comment: If it does not work, then again it means that what you provided in the question does not correctly represent your code. My answer works on the code and payload that you provided. But what's happening exactly now?

Comment: I receive the same error and output from print(event) that i wrote in question

Comment: its not possible to get same error, based on your question.

Comment: I took lambda code & payload from https://medium.com/javarevisited/trigger-the-alert-message-to-ms-team-using-aws-sns-and-lambda-function-1c7769012eff, full code is there. Also my SNS uses encryption, maybe it affects somehow

Answer (score 1):

The `Message` is a string like this:

```
"{\"alertname\": \"CPU_Alert\", \"status\": \"firing\", \"host_name\": \"host1\", \"cloud_account_id\": \"1234567890\", \"cloud_region\": \"eu-west-1\", \"summary\": \"High CPU Load\", \"severity\": \"warning\"}"
```

You need to decode the string into a dict.

I.E. `json.loads(thestring)`

```
> foo = "{\"alertname\": \"CPU_Alert\", \"status\": \"firing\", \"host_name\": \"host1\", \"cloud_account_id\": \"1234567890\", \"cloud_region\": \"eu-west-1\", \"summary\": \"High CPU Load\", \"severity\": \"warning\"}"
> foo
'{"alertname": "CPU_Alert", "status": "firing", "host_name": "host1", "cloud_account_id": "1234567890", "cloud_region": "eu-west-1", "summary": "High CPU Load", "severity": "warning"}'
> import json
> bar = json.loads(foo)
> bar['alertname']
'CPU_Alert'
```

Catch the `KeyError` and see what you got:

```
foo = "{\"notalertname\": \"surprise\"}"
try:
    message = json.loads(foo)
    alertname = message['alertname']
except KeyError:
    print(f"KeyError: {message.items()}")
    
KeyError: dict_items([('notalertname', 'surprise')])
```

Comment: I decode the string with this code: message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']). Is this correct code?

Comment: No, i receive an error that i wrote above

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You'll have to start debugging.  Maybe do stuff like `logger.info(type(message))` and `logger.info(message.keys())`

Comment: You might want to stick a `try...except KeyError:...` around it and log the values of the variables that fail.  It is probably getting something that does not fit your assumed structure of a dict with the key "alertname".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) python package on the `event` first to get the valid `message`, and then you can use `json` to get your `alertname`:

```
import ast

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))

    records = ast.literal_eval(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    message = json.loads(records['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))

    alertname = message['alertname']
    status = message['status']
```

p.s.
May need to implement iteration over all `event['Records']` in case you get more then one record from sns.